# Process queue with redux-saga

Tags: redux, generator, redux-saga

I am trying to implement a queue handler for managing notifications with a redux-saga generator.

Basically, I need to show notifications sequentually as they enter the queue.

For this, I have a `queue` array in the redux store, an action `QUQUE_NOTIFICATION` action to add to queue and `SHOW_NOTIFICATION` to remove a notification for queue.

My current saga implementation is that simple :

```
export function* watchQueue() {
    while (true) {
        const state = yield select()
        const queue = state.queue
        if (queue.length > 0) {
            yield put({ action: 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION', queue[0])
        }
        yield call(delay, 5000);
      }
    }
}
```

The problem with current implementation is that when a queue is empty a `QUQUE_NOTIFICATION` is dispatched generator can be waiting for the delay to finish.
However, I want to show the first notification as soon as it enters the queue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same idea for showing up notification (queueing them) however saga provides already implemented solution in terms of channels.
I have:

```
export function * notificationSaga () {                                                  
  const requestChan = yield actionChannel(Notification.request)                          
  while (true) {                                                                         
    const { payload } = yield take(requestChan)                                          
    yield call(showNotification, payload)                                                
  }                                                                                      
}
```

which I believe is elegant solution to your problem.
showNotification is another function which actually shows notifications and waits a bit before taking it down.