# Is there a Redux Saga that creates like a queue and wait until first redux-saga generator effect is finished then get next from some queue

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, queue

I learn Redux (beginner)and I read about [Redux Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/)

Here are the most common effects - I can't see how to construct my code like I want it.

```
takeMaybe(channel)
takeEvery(pattern, saga, ...args)
takeEvery(channel, saga, ...args)
takeLatest(pattern, saga, ..args)
takeLatest(channel, saga, ..args)
takeLeading(pattern, saga, ..args)
```

I read some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242398/process--with-redux-saga) answers about this but can't find a solution. In my case I wanted to let the middleware Saga handle a of files like User select files and the Saga must do some checking on every file like creating a hash and connect Firestore for metadata. I wanted this to happen in sequentially so if User select 1000 files the browser doesn't crumble.

The `takeLatest` killes the current running so that will not work and the `takeEvery` will spawn a new thread on ever file.

How could I fix this in my scenario? Maybe I must create my own queue code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's easy to do

Have `fileReducer: initialState= {files:[], proccesingFile: false}`
When you need to add file to queue dispatch `FILE_ADDED` action with `file_data` and add the data to `fileReducer.files`

Use `takeEvery` on `FILE_ADDED` in function see if `proccesingFile` is `true`, if it is `true` do nothing just return.. if it's false then start your upload process and all.. once that's done.. trigger `FILE_UPLOADED` action..

Use `takeEvery` on `FILE_UPLOADED`, in that remove file that's uploaded and check if files array is empty.. if it's empty just return or else see if `proccesingFile` is `true`, if it is `true` do nothing just return.. if it's false then start your upload process of first element once that's done.. trigger `FILE_UPLOADED` action again..

> This process will continue till `files` is empty array..
> Things go asynchronously so the browser don't crumble

> Note : in `takeEvery` `FILE_UPLOADED`we are checking if `proccesingFile` is `true`just to make sure we are not uploading multiple files at once..

If you think something is not clear, ready to help..